# "I don't think I'll succeed but I ........... as well try."

Tags: word-choice

Could you possibly help me on what is the right answer for this question please?

1. can
2. may
3. should
4. must

I went for 3 but my book says it is wrong. Actually for me all options fit the question.
Is this a special (like maybe other options could be right but you can not change any word like maxim) structure ?

By the way does **as well** mean    *anyway* here? 
Can we omit *as well* or replace it?

Thanks

Comment: *May* is correct, although *might* is probably more common. See [this page](http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-cobuild/may/might%20as%20well), Number 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I'd go with the second option: *may*. The structure *may as well* & *might as well* are used to express what is thought to be the easiest or most logical choice. According to the [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/may-as-well-and-might-as-well):

> We can use may as well and might as well for making suggestions. We can use them to say what we think is the easiest or most logical course of action when we cannot see a better alternative. They are both fairly informal. Might as well is more common than may as well.

In this case, I'd say yes, *might/may as well* as a whole, not just *as well* could mean *anyway*. It suggests some sort of resignation upon the idea of being already convinced that one won't succeed, however you have nothing to lose if you try. *Might as well give it a try* ;)

Comment: well your answer sparked another question im my mind.. what is the difference between  " might as well give it a try "  and   just "give it a try " ?

Comment: Check "I don't think I'll succeed but I *can/should/must* give it a try." & see if you can find the difference between the one you ask and the other options that raise when using simply *give it a try*, if you're still not convinced, feel free to post a new question :)

Comment: Fair enough.Before I saw your answer to my main question I  thought in the same way so all options would fit:) But now I know " might /may as well " is a "phrase " .